# How to run bloom filter function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I run a bloom filter function on BigQuery?

I've tried to look for such a function, but I can't find it. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with an integer column. In BigQuery integers are stored as 64 bit numbers. Don't store numbers as a sequence of 0s and 1s (binary).

Some example data:

```
Number

154 (in binary 10011010)
53  (in binary 00110101)
148 (in binary 10010100)
38  (in binary 00100110)
59  (in binary 00111011)
106 (in binary 01101010)
```

And you need to find all entries matching 24 (00011000).

Then you can run a query like:

```
SELECT *
 FROM
  (SELECT 154 AS n),
  (SELECT 53 AS n),
  (SELECT 148 AS n),
  (SELECT 38 AS n),
  (SELECT 59 AS n),
  (SELECT 106 AS n)
WHERE n & 24 = 24
```

This returns:

```
154
59
```

Soon in BigQuery you will be able to run UDF - user defined functions in the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) language.

Comment: But this is not how bloom filter works - it needs to compute (multiple) indecies by applying some hash functions, and then check if element at that position is present.